# Скачивание и загрузка приложения на Itunes connection

Tags: ios

Есть 2 оплаченных аккаунта iOs разработчика: один на физ. лицо, другой на юр. лицо. На первом аккаунте есть опубликованное приложение, требуется скачать его репозиторий, немного изменить название и залить это приложение на второй аккаунт. До этого никогда не сталкивался с iOS. Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно, чтобы совершить вышеуказанные действия желательно по шагам :) но, можно ссылку на какую-нибудь статью или гайд, а так же требуется ли мне XCode, могу ли я сделать задуманное используя только винду и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить не получится, всё, что является частью архива приложения неизменяемо с момента заливки, вам понадобится исходный код приложения. Но само приложение можно перенести с одного аккаунта на другой, для этого нужно обращаться в поддержку Apple.

Comment: Я видел функцию переноса приложения, но как я понимаю, при переносе нельзя будет изменить имя пакета, что бы в при скачивании пользователем в AppStore было другое описание? Например с com.pupkin.testapp на com.microsoft.testapp? 
Второй вытекающий вопрос, как я понял нельзя скачать этот архив из itunes connect, так?

Comment: Пакет скачать нельзя. Но его можно, например, поставить тестфлайтом или с аппстора на телефон, и оттуда достать, но это не поможет модифицировать пакет. Описание на аппсторе поменять можно, а имя аппа на хоум скрине - нет. По поводу смены bundle id - у меня закрались сомнения, так как мне кажется, что при переносе аппа у нас менялся bundle id, но с другой стороны это нелогично, ибо для этого понадобилось бы переподписывать апп, так что скорее всего неправильно мне кажется. Но пересабмитать ситый деливери, более того - модифицированный - не получится.

Comment: ситый деливери? можно расшифровку, пожалуйста)

Comment: слитый, скачаный с айтюнса